# Not able to read file in Pypandoc

Tags: python-3.x, pandoc, document-conversion, pypandoc

I am trying to covert a pdf to html using Pandoc. I have installed pandoc binary , added the environment variable path and then using

```
import pypandoc
import os

os.environ.setdefault('PYPANDOC_PANDOC', 'C://Program Files//Pandoc//pandoc.exe')


file_path = r"D:/46580375_1593783098922.pdf"
output = pypandoc.convert_file("46580375_1593783098922.pdf", to='html', outputfile= 'test.html')
```

It is giving me an error :

```
RuntimeError: Invalid input format! Got "pdf" but expected one of
these: commonmark, creole, csv, docbook, docx, dokuwiki, epub, fb2,
gfm, haddock, html, ipynb, jats, jira, json, latex, man, markdown,
markdown_github, markdown_mmd, markdown_phpextra, markdown_strict,
mediawiki, muse, native, odt, opml, org, rst, t2t, textile, tikiwiki,
twiki, vimwiki
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

As the error said, **you can't convert PDF to HTML via `pandoc`**.